# How to merge multiple columns with same names in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field':'FAPERF',
               'Form':'LIVERID',
               'Folder':'ALL',
               'Logline':'9',
               'Data':'Yes',
               'Data':'Blank',
               'Data':'No',
               'Logline':'10'}) '''
```

I need dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Field':['FAPERF','FAPERF'],
               'Form':['LIVERID','LIVERID'],
               'Folder':['ALL','ALL'],
               'Logline':['9','10'],
               'Data':['Yes','Blank','No']}) '''
```

I had tried using the below code but not able to achieve desired output.

`res3.set_index(res3.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True['Data'].unstack(0)`

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: you cannot have this dictionary

Comment: In addition to @ansev comment, effective dictionary definition leads to: `{'Field': 'FAPERF',
 'Form': 'LIVERID',
 'Folder': 'ALL',
 'Logline': '10',
 'Data': 'No'}` which I suppose is not what You expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best option is to create multiple data frames with the same column name ( example 3 df with column name : "Data"  ) then simply perform a concat function over Data frames :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Field':'FAPERF',
           'Form':'LIVERID',
           'Folder':'ALL',
           'Logline':'9',
           'Data':'Yes'}

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({
           'Data':'No',
           'Logline':'10'})

 df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Data':'Blank'})



frames = [df1, df2, df3]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: Hi Andres, the values in the logline and Data will be changing and they will not be constant, could you please help me with respect to this. Thank you

Comment: If that is the case, then I would suggest building just one data frame and usinfg

Comment: "for row, rows in df.iterrows():   " iterate over every line of dataframe and append a new result. Or simply adding  creating a dictionary with the specific keys and adding the elements , without pandas, just basic python dictionary.

Comment: still not able to achieve the output, can you please help me Andres

Comment: Hi Andres thank you for the answer, your new solution seems to be working, but can you please help me how do we handle if we have dynamic value in Form and Field as well

Comment: see how I create the lists for the dynamic types and how you fill the new_dict inside the for loop, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to list in which you specify the logline and data_type for each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_df = []

data_type_list = ["yes","no","Blank"]
logline_type = ["9","10",'10']


for x in range (len(data_type_list)):

    new_dict = { 'Field':['FAPERF'], 'Form':['LIVERID'],'Folder':['ALL'],"Data" : [data_type_list[x]], "Logline" : [logline_type[x]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
    list_df.append(df)

new_df = pd.concat(list_df)


print(new_df)
```